# How to Obtain Youngest Child's PID from task_struct

Tags: c, linux, struct, kernel, child-process

I'm working on a project that involves writing a new system call for Linux 3.18.20.  This system call is supposed to store various information about the currently running process in a newly defined struct.

One of the fields of the struct is the PID of the process's youngest child, and I've been searching for information about this in the struct task_struct, as defined here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h.  I've been testing my new system call, and I can't seem to find the appropriate PID value from the struct list_head children.

My test function involves forking a child, storing the return value of fork, and comparing it to the value I get from doing various things in the parent's task_struct.  I got the parent's task_struct, and I tried all of the following macros for struct list_head to get the correct PID.  None of them have been correct.

```
    printk("list_next_entry pid = %d\n", list_next_entry(task, children)->pid);
printk("list_prev_entry pid = %d\n", list_prev_entry(task, children)->pid);
printk("list_entry pid = %d\n", list_entry(&task->children, struct task_struct, children)->pid);
printk("list_first_entry pid = %d\n", list_first_entry(&task->children, struct task_struct, children)->pid);
printk("list_last_entry pid = %d\n", list_last_entry(&task->children, struct task_struct, children)->pid);
```

Is this even close to the correct way to try to find the youngest child of the parent process?  How can I find a process's youngest child's PID from that process's task_struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments to fields in `task_struct` note, `children` is

> list of my children

and `siblings` is

> linkage in my parent's children list

So pointer to the first children task can be requested using

```
list_first_entry(&task->children, struct task_struct, siblings)
```

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.

Answer (score 0):

One process can get the youngest process pid from it's last `fork(2)` system call it made.  You'll have to patch the `clone(2)` system call (as it's the base for al fork calls in linux) and store the pid of the returning process in the u-area (or whatever its called in linux kernel) so you can get it from there when the user calls your system call.